# Posting to the Facebook game ticker

Tags: php, facebook, ticker, news-ticker

Is it possible to post directly to the Facebook game ticker? As you might if you were sending an app request for example?

As I understand you can post actions to the ticker, but I was just wondering if it's possible to post a string to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look,

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/