# How to publish 'X is playing MyGame' on news ticker in Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, news-ticker

When my friends are playing Facebook-based games, I see "Friend's Name is playing Game's Name" in the news ticker. How can I achieve the same functionality for an iOS Game? Is there a special way of doing this, or is it just done using the Open Graph actions and objects?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548384/posting-to-the-facebook-game-ticker

Comment: the answer at the link only talks about publishing scores and achievements (which i've already implemented). i am trying to create the exact string "x is playing y" in news ticker.

Comment: Those are automatic 'discovery stories' - you can't post them manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are automatic 'discovery stories' - you can't post them manually

Comment: didn't know the name of it, so I'll be using Open Graph to *imitate* discovery stories manually. thanks.

Comment: I don't think 'play' actions will be approved, but good luck :)