# Android :: Facebook like button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I'm learning how to use the Facebook SDK, and i like to put a like button to the application i'm testing on it, and unfortunately i'm doing something wrong, so can you please show a sample or a code that apply the like button, here is the class that am working on.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2010-present Facebook.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.PACKAGE_NAME;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
import com.facebook.model.GraphPlace;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog;
import com.facebook.widget.FriendPickerFragment;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment;
import com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment;
import com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.OnCompleteListener;

public class FacebookClass extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";
    private static final Location SEATTLE_LOCATION = new Location("") {
        {
            setLatitude(47.6097);
            setLongitude(-122.3331);
        }
    };

    private final String PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY = "com.PACKAGE_NAME:PendingAction";

    private Button postStatusUpdateButton;
    // private Button postPhotoButton;
    private Button pickFriendsButton;
    // private Button pickPlaceButton;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView greeting;
    private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    private ViewGroup controlsContainer;
    private GraphUser user;
    private GraphPlace place;
    private List<GraphUser> tags;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialog;

    private enum PendingAction {
        NONE, POST_PHOTO, POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private FacebookDialog.Callback dialogCallback = new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
                Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
                Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String name = savedInstanceState
                    .getString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY);
            pendingAction = PendingAction.valueOf(name);
        }

        // try {
        // PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
        // "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook",
        // PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        // for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        // MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        // md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        // Log.d("YOURHASH KEY:",
        // Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        // }
        // } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // System.out.println();
        // } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // System.out.println();
        // } catch (Exception e) {
        // // TODO: handle exception
        // System.out.println();
        // }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_more);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton
                .setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                        FacebookClass.this.user = user;
                        updateUI();
                        // It's possible that we were waiting for this.user to
                        // be populated in order to post a
                        // status update.
                        handlePendingAction();
                    }
                });

        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        greeting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);

        postStatusUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postStatusUpdateButton);
        postStatusUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostStatusUpdate();
            }
        });

        // postPhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postPhotoButton);
        // postPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // public void onClick(View view) {
        // onClickPostPhoto();
        // }
        // });

        pickFriendsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickFriendsButton);
        pickFriendsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPickFriends();
            }
        });

        // pickPlaceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickPlaceButton);
        // pickPlaceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // public void onClick(View view) {
        // onClickPickPlace();
        // }
        // });

        controlsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_ui_container);

        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment != null) {
            // If we're being re-created and have a fragment, we need to a) hide
            // the main UI controls and
            // b) hook up its listeners again.
            controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (fragment instanceof FriendPickerFragment) {
                setFriendPickerListeners((FriendPickerFragment) fragment);
            } else if (fragment instanceof PlacePickerFragment) {
                setPlacePickerListeners((PlacePickerFragment) fragment);
            }
        }

        // Listen for changes in the back stack so we know if a fragment got
        // popped off because the user
        // clicked the back button.
        fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                    // We need to re-show our UI.
                    controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        canPresentShareDialog = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this,
                FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();

        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingAction.name());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, dialogCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
                && (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException || exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(FacebookClass.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                    .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).show();
            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
        } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
            handlePendingAction();
        }
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        boolean enableButtons = (session != null && session.isOpened());

        postStatusUpdateButton.setEnabled(enableButtons
                || canPresentShareDialog);
        // postPhotoButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);
        pickFriendsButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);
        // pickPlaceButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);

        if (enableButtons && user != null) {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
            greeting.setText(getString(R.string.hello_user, user.getFirstName()));
        } else {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
            greeting.setText(null);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but
        // we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
        case POST_PHOTO:
            postPhoto();
            break;
        case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
            postStatusUpdate();
            break;
        }
    }

    private interface GraphObjectWithId extends GraphObject {
        String getId();
    }

    private void showPublishResult(String message, GraphObject result,
            FacebookRequestError error) {
        String title = null;
        String alertMessage = null;
        if (error == null) {
            title = getString(R.string.success);
            String id = result.cast(GraphObjectWithId.class).getId();
            alertMessage = getString(R.string.successfully_posted_post,
                    message, id);
        } else {
            title = getString(R.string.error);
            alertMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(title).setMessage(alertMessage)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).show();
    }

    private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE, canPresentShareDialog);
    }

    private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilder() {

        return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setName("Hi")
                .setDescription("Hello D")
                .setLink(
                        "LINK")
                .setPicture(
                        "http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/facebook-android-clean1.png?w=259");
    }

    // ///////////////////////////////////
    private void publishFeedDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        params.putString("caption",
                "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        params.putString(
                "description",
                "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        params.putString("picture",
                "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
                Session.getActiveSession(), params)).setOnCompleteListener(
                new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Posted story, id: " + postId,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }

                }).build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////

    // private FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder
    // createActionDialogBuilder() {
    //
    // new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(MoreActivity.this,
    // OpenGraphAction.this.setType("me/PROJECT_NAME:start"), "like",
    // "");
    // return null;
    //
    // }

    private void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            // FacebookDialog shareDialog = createActionDialogBuilder().build();
            // publishFeedDialog();
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilder().build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            final String message = getString(R.string.status_update,
                    user.getFirstName(), (new Date().toString()));
            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), message, place, tags,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult(message,
                                    response.getGraphObject(),
                                    response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }

    private void onClickPostPhoto() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO, false);
    }

    private void postPhoto() {
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.icon);
            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), image, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post),
                                    response.getGraphObject(),
                                    response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
        }
    }

    private void showPickerFragment(PickerFragment<?> fragment) {
        fragment.setOnErrorListener(new PickerFragment.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment,
                    FacebookException error) {
                String text = getString(R.string.exception, error.getMessage());
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(FacebookClass.this, text,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();

        controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // We want the fragment fully created so we can use it immediately.
        fm.executePendingTransactions();

        fragment.loadData(false);
    }

    private void onClickPickFriends() {
        final FriendPickerFragment fragment = new FriendPickerFragment();

        setFriendPickerListeners(fragment);

        showPickerFragment(fragment);
    }

    private void setFriendPickerListeners(final FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        fragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new FriendPickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                onFriendPickerDone(fragment);
            }
        });
    }

    private void onFriendPickerDone(FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();

        String results = "";

        List<GraphUser> selection = fragment.getSelection();
        tags = selection;
        if (selection != null && selection.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (GraphUser user : selection) {
                names.add(user.getName());
            }
            results = TextUtils.join(", ", names);
        } else {
            results = getString(R.string.no_friends_selected);
        }

        showAlert(getString(R.string.you_picked), results);
    }

    private void onPlacePickerDone(PlacePickerFragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();

        String result = "";

        GraphPlace selection = fragment.getSelection();
        if (selection != null) {
            result = selection.getName();
        } else {
            result = getString(R.string.no_place_selected);
        }

        place = selection;

        showAlert(getString(R.string.you_picked), result);
    }

    private void onClickPickPlace() {
        final PlacePickerFragment fragment = new PlacePickerFragment();
        fragment.setLocation(SEATTLE_LOCATION);
        fragment.setTitleText(getString(R.string.pick_seattle_place));

        setPlacePickerListeners(fragment);

        showPickerFragment(fragment);
    }

    private void setPlacePickerListeners(final PlacePickerFragment fragment) {
        fragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new PlacePickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                onPlacePickerDone(fragment);
            }
        });
        fragment.setOnSelectionChangedListener(new PlacePickerFragment.OnSelectionChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectionChanged(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                if (fragment.getSelection() != null) {
                    onPlacePickerDone(fragment);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showAlert(String title, String message) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(title).setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).show();
    }

    private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null
                && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

    private void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoSession) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            pendingAction = action;
            if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                // We can do the action right away.
                handlePendingAction();
                return;
            } else if (session.isOpened()) {
                // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when
                // we get called back.
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        this, PERMISSION));
                return;
            }
        }

        if (allowNoSession) {
            pendingAction = action;
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help??

Comment: check this post, there is well-formed library to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853937/1891118

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the id of the post that you want to like and store it in **`fbPostId`**.

Then, inside the onClickHandler of your like button, put the following code snippet :

```
Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), fbPostId + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
         }
});
Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but one more thing, how to get the fbPostId?

Comment: Whenever any post is published on Facebook using the API, it returns the id of that post, which you can store and later pass to this function.

Comment: i may miss led you, sorry, what i meant is that i need is like this: "Swayam has like a question on stack overflow", and i have inserted a button for that, just need the next step.

Comment: Oh, okay. But to know which question is in the context, you need to have the id which represents the question, right ? How are you identifying the question ?

Comment: It's actually my first time, so i don't think that i'm following you here, but what if there is no id for the question? Sorry for my inexperience. :)

Comment: No no. No need to apologize. We all were beginners at some point of time. See, the thing is that every post as an id associated with it. It is like a primary key for that post. So, the question/post will definitely have an id. Now, your question will be how to get the id. But to be able to answer your question, I would need to know how exactly are you getting the post/question to be liked. I mean, the user is liking a particular post. How are you getting that post ?

Comment: Oh okay, now i get it, i have a list of questions in an arraylist, each one of them has its own like button, so when i click on the like button, it will post something like: "Swayam Like question using/via Tayseer app" something like that, so i think i have to share it and put the info that i need in the post, right?

Comment: Oh, so you have your own questions and not posts on facebook? I was assuming that you were talking about liking a post/question on facebook. But I think that you are talking about publishing user activity on Ticker, right ?

Comment: Something on these lines maybe ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181625/how-to-publish-x-is-playing-mygame-on-news-ticker-in-facebook