# callback cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have been trying to add a facebook like button into my Android App.
I followed everything from the facebook developers site including from installing facebook-sdk to following their code.
On doing everything I now find a error in my App which I am unable to go through.
I searched through a number of resources for solutions but could never get a working one.

This is how i implemented it. 
The codes below represent my MainActivity.java

```
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.LikeView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);

    LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
    likeView.setObjectId("https://www.facebook.com/NewsNrnDotCom");
  .
  .
  .

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, null);
 }
}
```

And the codes for the file activity_main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LikeView
        android:id="@+id/like_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nrnlogo" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything is fine but with the code

```
  uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
```

There is an error message which says:

```
"callback cannot be resolved to a variable"
```

I am unable to find where did I make an error. 
I have here added just the few related code so as to prevent looking bulky.
I can add any more code if needed.

Comment: where is callback declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missing to declare [Session.StatusCallback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2#step2) in your activity :

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

Comment: Okay fine, I added the code you provided. But now I am confused on which imports should i make. I am offered with a number of options.
Can u tell me in particular??

Comment: Try this : import com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback

Answer (score 2):

You must declare what **callback** means.

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

However, as your code looks like, it might lead to another errors. 
Please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475986/android-facebook-like-button) to avoid more issues.

Comment: that's pure help coming from you,bro.. take a cake